# Graph plotting libraries for Java

Tags: java, graph

What are the best graph plotting libraries for Java? (preferably also supporting 3D graphs)

Comment: Just to get it right, do you need them for plotting mathematical functions and stuff? Or to show Data statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i needed something like that a few years ago. I used Jgraphplot

http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php?id=faq_beginners

the project itsself seems to be fallen asleep but i don't think there was to much change to maths sience since 2003 :-)

So if i google for tools like that there is no newer tool at all. It covers 3d Graphs as well.

Answer (score 2):

JFreeChart seems to come highly recommended (or at least is often used).

Answer (score 0):

My open source project, DataDisplay, does just what you want.

https://sourceforge.net/p/msu-doe-dd/